# Не реализуется геттер?

Tags: java

есть такой код. Не могу вызвать геттер из класса Flower. Понятно почему, потому что он не статический и на момент его вызова объекты класса Flower отсутствуют. Но фактически они есть, так как я выше создаю три массива из объектов наследуемых классов от Flowers(розы, тюльпаны и орхидеи) НО(!) внутри метода createFlowers. Как сделать так чтобы геттер "чувствовал" не явное создание объекта в методе мейн, а посредством метода класса этого объекта. Или 
может я что то совсем делаю не так? Прошу не кидать палками учусь ровно месяц :)

```
public class FlowerShop {
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

....тут ничего важного и влияющего на проблему, далее

```
    if (viewAssortiment.equals("нет")) { // Клиент не зашел в магазин
        seller.SaysGoodBye();

    } else if (viewAssortiment.equals("да")) { // Клиент зашел в магазин
        Rose.createFlowers("Роза", 600, 15);
        Tulip.createFlowers("Тюльпан", 450, 25);
        Orchid.createFlowers("Орхидея", 400, 21);

        seller.ShowsAssortment(someFlowers.getFlowerName);} ЭТОТ ГЕТТЕР ГОРИТ КРАСНЫМ

public class Flower {

private String flowerName;
private int flowerCost;
private int currentNumberOfFlowers;

public String getFlowerName() {        ВОТ ЭТОТ ГЕТТЕР!
    return flowerName;
}

public int getFlowerCost() {
    return flowerCost;
}
public int getCurrentNumberOfFlowers(){
    return currentNumberOfFlowers;
}

public Flower(String flowerName, int flowerCost) { // конструктор
    this.flowerName = flowerName;
    this.flowerCost = flowerCost;

}

public static void createFlowers(String flowerName, int flowerCost, int currentNumberOfFlowers) { // массивы различных видов цветов в разном количестве
    int i;
    Flower[] someFlowers = new Flower[currentNumberOfFlowers];
    for (i = 0; i < someFlowers.length; i++) {
        someFlowers[i] = new Flower(flowerName, flowerCost);
    }

}
public class Seller { // Класс Продавец
public void ShowsAssortment (String x) {
    System.out.println("На текущий момент в магазине имеются: " + x );
}
```

}

Очень буду благодарен за помощь особенно если объясните подробней мою ошибку)

Comment: "Не могу вызвать геттер из класса Flower" - где?

Comment: В someFlowers что хранится? И я попрошу поправить фигурные скобки и отступы, а то получается, что у вас класс Flower внутри if.

Comment: @igor В методе мейн

Comment: @trollingchar в массиве someFlowers хранятся объекты класса

Comment: так геттер это обычная функция, и для ее вызова нужны `()`

Comment: вы можете обойти массив с помощью цикла: `for (Flower flower : someFlowers) { String name = flower.getFlowerName(); ... }`. Вместо ... делаете обработку строки

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Flower[] createFlowers(String flowerName, int flowerCost, int currentNumberOfFlowers) { // массивы различных видов цветов в разном количестве
    int i;
    Flower[] someFlowers = new Flower[currentNumberOfFlowers];
    for (i = 0; i < someFlowers.length; i++) {
        someFlowers[i] = new Flower(flowerName, flowerCost);
    }
    return someFlowers;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Flower[] someFlowers = Flower.createFlowers("Tulip", 5, 3);
  for (int i = 0; i < someFlowers.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(someFlowers[i].getFlowerName());
  }
}
```